# seaborn heatmap labels can't be display clearly

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a problem storing labels in my Seaborn heatmap. The labels I have are pretty long.

```
correlation = df.corr()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.heatmap(correlation, vmax=1, square=True,annot=True,cmap='cubehelix')
plt.title('Correlation between different fearures')
```

You can see the map:

[image: here]

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
correlation = df.corr()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
g = sns.heatmap(correlation, vmax=1, square=True,annot=True,cmap='cubehelix',xticklabels=True,yticklabels=True)
g.set_yticklabels(g.get_yticklabels(), rotation =0)
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_yticklabels(), rotation =90)
plt.title('Correlation between different fearures')
```

Comment: Why are you rotating the xticklabels 1 degree?

Comment: @mwaskom i think 1 here means 90* but, i am not quite sure about this.

Comment: willing to resize the font